# How to simplify an extensive C if statement?

Tags: c, if-statement, simplify, arc4random

I am wondering what the best way is to approach this problem. I have a randomizing function set up that takes 8 strings as input and outputs a random one of them. I would like this randomizer to disregard all strings which have no value. For example, if I have strings text#, where # is 1-8, and let's say text5 and text7 have no text, then I want the randomizing function to check if any to use only use text#, where # is 1-8 but not 5 or 7.

Comment: Watch out for the case where all 8 of them are empty.

Comment: You write software for this sort of thing.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Yikes! Put the strings in an array instead of having 8 different variables. Then use a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

1. Count the list for valid strings.
2. Form random number `(rand() % Count)`.
3. Find the matching string.

Sample code

```
int StringCount = 8;
char *String[StringCount];

// populate `Sting` somehow

// count valid strings
int Count = 0;
for (int i=0; i<StringCount; i++) {
  if (ValidString(String[i])) Count++;
}

if (Count == 0) Handle_NoGoodStrings();
int random_number = rand()%Count;

int i;
for (i=0; i<StringCount; i++) {
  if (ValidString(String[i])) {
    if (Count == random_number) {
      break; 
    }
  }
}

// String[i] is the string
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Put the strings in an array
2. Choose a random index into the array, using your random function
3. Use code similar to:

```
    int i;
    for (i = index; i != index; i = (i+1) % numitems)
    {
        /* check we have a string and it isn't empty */
        if (strings[i] && *strings[i])
            return strings[i];
    }
    return NULL;
```

assuming `index` is your random number between 0 and `numitems` -1.